# Why could I use eclipse to connect MySQL 8.0.13 successfully but failed in cmd mode? (my Java JDK is 11.0.1)

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse

**Why could I use eclipse to connect MySQL 8.0.13 successfully but failed in cmd mode? (my Java JDK is 11.0.1)**

*In cmd mode, it showed this wrong message:↓*

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:315)
        at chapter20_JDBC.SimpleDBSource.<init>(SimpleDBSource.java:28)
        at chapter20_JDBC.SimpleDBSource.<init>(SimpleDBSource.java:18)
        at chapter20_JDBC.ConnectionDemo.main(ConnectionDemo.java:11)
```

Comment: Did you include mysql-connector jar in your classpath while running from cmd?

Comment: Hi Pushpesh Kumar : Thank you for your helpful tip so that I have solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to add "mysql-connector-java-8.0.13.jar" to my windows 10's CLASSPATH environment variant using ";" to add to the second variant and solve the problem.
[C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\Connector J 8.0\mysql-connector-java-8.0.13.jar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hesaQ.jpg)